# Getting connection refused error while hitting a URL

Tags: rest, post, http-post, httpclient

I am trying to hit a url through HttpClient api,PostMethod api passing json as input value which I'm inserting it in the Entity part of post method.
Based on the json input only I'l be getting the output value. 
But while executing the execute(postMethod) I'm getting connection refused error.

Comment: Check the resource and your own ability to connect to it via an alternative method.

Comment: Tried hitting the url from google, I'm getting error response. Based on the json input value only, the response will be there. Input value I cant try it manually since its post method

Comment: how about using a tool like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en)?

Comment: Getting error response when onsite members tries to access the url through the same code. But getting connection refused error when I try. Accessing the same url through browser I am getting proper response.